# Select and left join: Error: could not find function, Syntax issue?

Tags: r, syntax, dplyr

I believe I might have a syntax issue on my hands. I am using a `left_join` function together with `select` as follows:

```
df<- df %>% left_join(select(df2, matchcode, 
tottax, indiv, corp, indirect, gst, trade), by="matchcode")
```

This works without problem. Next, I want to add columns from a different dataset. This dataset has columns with shitty names and spaces so I " cleaned" the names as follows:

```
names(df3) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(df3))
names(df3) <- gsub("%", "p", names(df3))
```

I then tried to apply the exact same formula. Below is the actual syntax:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% left_join(select(df3, matchcode, 
Firms_that_do_not_report_all_sales_for_tax_purposes_(p_of_firms),
Firms_visited_or_required_meetings_with_tax_officials_(p_of_firms)), by="matchcode")
```

The error is as follows:

```
Error in Firms_that_do_not_report_all_sales_for_tax_purposes_(p_of_firms) : 
  could not find function "Firms_that_do_not_report_all_sales_for_tax_purposes_"
```

Is there still a syntax issue with my column names?

Comment: When the parser reads something like `a(b)` it interprets `a` as being a function. You should either clean the parentheses, or keep them and use backticks to refer to that column.

Comment: You are right, I have removed the brackets, but the variables keep giving me all kinds of trouble. I'm trying to find a more elegant solution to deal. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: It is unclear what the Firm_* objects are. Is that psuedocode? User-defined functions that return column names?

Comment: "cleaned the names" use `make.names` instead.